# flow control depending on value of xml element

Tags: php, xml

I have a long xml data file with 500+ items in it, it comes in this form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<CATALOG>
<ITEM>
    <TITLE>ITEM name</TITLE>
    <TYPE>TYPE </TYPE>
    <DESCIPTION>DESCIPTIONiliate Page CPM</DESCIPTION>
    <PRICE>PRICE</PRICE>
    <ITEM>http://mysite.com/item-link</ITEM>
</ITEM>
</CATALOG>
```

and I use the following code in the php page to import data from the xml file:

```
<?php
$ITEMSS = new SimpleXMLElement('ITEMS.xml', null, true);

echo <<<EOF
<table width="100%" align="center" border="1" bordercolor="#0099ff" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">

    <tr>
            <th bgcolor="#66ccff"><span class="style4">ITEM Name</span></th>
            <th bgcolor="#66ccff"><span class="style4">item TYPE </span></th>
            <th bgcolor="#66ccff"><span class="style4">item DESCIPTION </span></th>
            <th bgcolor="#66ccff"><span class="style4">item PRICE</span></th>
            <th bgcolor="#66ccff"><span class="style4">link to item</span></th>
    </tr>

EOF;
foreach($ITEMSS as $ITEMS) // loop through our DATAS
{
    echo <<<EOF
    <tr height="30" align=middle>
            <td><a href="{$ITEMS->ITEM}" target="_blank"><span class="STYLE7">{$ITEMS->TITLE}</span></a></td>
            <td><span class="STYLE8">{$ITEMS->TYPE}</span></td>
            <td><span class="STYLE8">{$ITEMS->DESCIPTION}</span></td>
            <td><span class="STYLE8">{$ITEMS->PRICE}</span></td>
            <td><a href="{$ITEMS->ITEM}" target="_blank"><B><span class="STYLE7">cHECK IT OUT</span></B></a></td>
    </tr>

EOF;
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

I need to add an "if" statement in the loop to select only some data if "TYPE" has a certain value, it will show that data, if not it will skip it.

Also need to add paging system, since there will be 500+ item to be listed, I want the table to show a miximum number of items, saying 25.

Thank you guys for your help!

Comment: You are welcome but I can't understand what I have to do.

Comment: please judge your head part `using “if” in php from xml`

Comment: Thanks to Fluffeh I solved the "if" problem, now I need to add paging system to show oly 25 items per page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative you could select (and process) only those ITEM elements that have a specific text value in the TYPE element via [xpath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/), e.g.

```
<?php
$doc = new SimpleXmlElement(getData());
foreach($doc->xpath("//ITEM[TYPE='A']") as $item) {
    echo $item->DESCIPTION, "\n";
}

function getData() {
    return <<< eox
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<CATALOG>
<ITEM>
    <TITLE>item 1</TITLE>
    <TYPE>A</TYPE>
    <DESCIPTION>desc1</DESCIPTION>
    <PRICE>price1</PRICE>
    <ITEM>item1-link</ITEM>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>
    <TITLE>item x</TITLE>
    <TYPE>B</TYPE>
    <DESCIPTION>descx</DESCIPTION>
    <PRICE>pricex</PRICE>
    <ITEM>itemx-link</ITEM>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>
    <TITLE>item y</TITLE>
    <TYPE>B</TYPE>
    <DESCIPTION>descy</DESCIPTION>
    <PRICE>pricey</PRICE>
    <ITEM>itemy-link</ITEM>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>
    <TITLE>item 2</TITLE>
    <TYPE>A</TYPE>
    <DESCIPTION>desc2</DESCIPTION>
    <PRICE>price2</PRICE>
    <ITEM>item2-link</ITEM>
</ITEM>
</CATALOG>
eox;
}
```

prints

```
desc1
desc2
```

-- edit: with some paging functionality --

```
<?php
define('ITEMS_PER_PAGE', 10);
$page = 1; // =intval($_GET['page']);

$posMin = $page*ITEMS_PER_PAGE;
$posMax = ($page+1)*ITEMS_PER_PAGE;
$doc = new SimpleXmlElement(getData());
foreach($doc->xpath("(//ITEM[TYPE='A'])[position()>=$posMin and position()<$posMax]") as $item) {
    echo $item->DESCIPTION, "\n";
}

function getData() {
    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<CATALOG>';
    for($i=0; $i<100; $i++) {
        $type = 0===$i%2 ? 'A':'B';
        $xml .= "   
        <ITEM>
        <TITLE>item $i</TITLE>
        <TYPE>$type</TYPE>
        <DESCIPTION>desc $i</DESCIPTION>
        <PRICE>price $i</PRICE>
        <ITEM>item{$i}-link</ITEM>
        </ITEM>";
    }
    $xml.='</CATALOG>';
    return $xml;
}
```

The function `getData()` is just some boilerplate that returns some xml data.
For understanding the xpath query have a read of a (good) xpath tutorial, see e.g. [Using XPATH to access XML elements (was: Good tutorial to learn xpath)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423920/using-xpath-to-access-xml-elements-was-good-tutorial-to-learn-xpath)

Comment: I don't understand , where should I inlclude the xml file to get data from, and where should I put that code to select some data and create a paging system?

Comment: It's a self-contained example, ready for copy&paste evaluation. It's not a "snip here and here and put there" code block.

Comment: I have a little problem , in the first page it shows only 4 items if I have 5 as a max per page, then it starts showing 5 items from the next page, also I added "next" and "previous" to show the next and previous page, but don't know how to stop at the last page, it keeps going up, and for the "previous" it keeps going down untill it showes -1 for the page !!

Answer (score 2):

You can add the loop as such:

```
foreach($ITEMSS as $ITEMS) // loop through our DATAS
{
    if($ITEMS->TYPE=="BoogeyWoogey")
    {
        echo <<<EOF
        <tr height="30" align=middle>
            <td><a href="{$ITEMS->ITEM}" target="_blank"><span class="STYLE7">{$ITEMS->TITLE}</span></a></td>
            <td><span class="STYLE8">{$ITEMS->TYPE}</span></td>
            <td><span class="STYLE8">{$ITEMS->DESCIPTION}</span></td>
            <td><span class="STYLE8">{$ITEMS->PRICE}</span></td>
            <td><a href="{$ITEMS->ITEM}" target="_blank"><B><span class="STYLE7">cHECK IT OUT</span></B></a></td>
        </tr>

EOF;
    }
}
```

Assuming that you are looping through the `foreach` and want to only display if the `$ITEMS->TYPE` property has the value `BoogeyWoogey` in it.

The Paging part will not be *quite* as simple.

You can do something like this:

You can add the loop as such:

```
$myLimit=(!empty($_REQUEST['myLimit']) ? $_REQUEST['myLimit'] : 0;
foreach($ITEMSS as $ITEMS) // loop through our DATAS
{
    for($i=$myLimit;$i<$myLimit+25;$i++)
    {
        if($ITEMS->ITEM=="BoogeyWoogey")
        {
            echo <<<EOF
            <tr height="30" align=middle>
                <td><a href="{$ITEMS->ITEM}" target="_blank"><span class="STYLE7">{$ITEMS->TITLE}</span></a></td>
                <td><span class="STYLE8">{$ITEMS->TYPE}</span></td>
                <td><span class="STYLE8">{$ITEMS->DESCIPTION}</span></td>
                <td><span class="STYLE8">{$ITEMS->PRICE}</span></td>
                <td><a href="{$ITEMS->ITEM}" target="_blank"><B><span class="STYLE7">cHECK IT OUT</span></B></a></td>
            </tr>

            EOF;
        }
    }
}
```

But you need to pass the variable $myLimit through a `$GET` or `$_POST` to the page to use it in the loop. (Feel free to change it to use a `$_SESSION` or anything else that suits your fancy - I figured using the variable in a link would be the easiest, so most likely a `$GET` should do the trick.

Comment: thank you so much, it works perfectly for the "if" part,   now I need the paging part , how can I list items in pages, saying site/item.php?page=1 and so on to list a maximum of 25 per page

Comment: "now I need the paging part" - That's a new question.

Comment: @VolkerK Well, he did ask it in the original, besides, I already wrote the code in a slap-together sort of way :)

Comment: darn... now I have to amend my answer, too :)

Comment: It was already included in the first question, but I just got the answer for the first part witch is "if" part.

Comment: when I add the second code to my page after "EOF;" I get this error "unexpected ';' " so how to solve it?

Comment: @JawadMira Remove any white space before the `EOF;` heredoc in the colde. I am updating my answer shortly. (I don't use the personally, but this seemed to resolve the issue on my test script here).